# Redirecting stdout to satisfy AWS CodeDeploy (Windows)

Tags: windows, batch-file, amazon-ec2, console-application, aws-code-deploy

I have a console application deploying to a Windows EC2 instance and can't figure out how to close stdout in such a way that satisfies AWS CodeDeploy (currently it hangs until timeout on the ApplicationStart hook and then errors out "Script at specified location: [start server script] failed to close STDOUT").

I've tried redirecting on the command line with the following start-server.bat:

`start "application name" [application path] > nul 2>&1 < nul
exit`

and I've tried redirecting in code with `Console.SetOut()` (C#).

Neither works and I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: Hi. Did you ever figure out a solution you could share? TIA.